# How to Take input in PHP-CLI (version 7.3) for a switch case variable?

Tags: php, switch-statement, user-input, php-7.3

My code looks like this :

```
switch ($input)
{
case "hello":
    .......code1..... ;
     break;
case "bye" :
     ......code2 .....;
     break;
case "xoxo":
     .......code3.....;
     break;
default:
    .......code4.....;

}
```

And I  am using `$input=fgets(STDIN)` to take the input but it doesn't execute the respective codes even if the case is matched.
A `var_dump($input);` or an `echo $input;` shows the value is assigned correctly (at least it looks to me). 
What do i need to add (or modify) in the codes ?

Comment: try `trim($input)`

Answer (score 0):

`$input=fgets(STDIN)` contains \n new line character at the end. Compare the two var dumps from this code:

```
$input=fgets(STDIN);
var_dump($input);
$input = rtrim($input);
var_dump($input);
```

and the output called with `$ echo 'hello' | php a.php`

```
string(6) "hello
"
string(5) "hello"
```

First one is 6 characters long: Hello + new line character, second one is exprected 5 characters long 'hello' string.